# Query for nested model returns duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

at the moment I am learning a lot about Laravel and eloquent, so please forgive my "stupid" questions.

### My goal

I'd like to `save` nested items and `get` them later with nested structure

**Example:**

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3246
     all: [
       App\Item {#3254
         id: 2,
         parent_id: null,
         title: "Parent",
         created_at: "2019-10-04 14:22:23",
         updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:22:23",
         children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3285
           all: [
             App\Item {#3287
               id: 3,
               parent_id: 2,
               title: "Child 1",
               created_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
               updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
             },
             App\Item {#3289
               id: 4,
               parent_id: 2,
               title: "Child 2",
               created_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
               updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

### Current result

My current result is this:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3246
     all: [
       App\Item {#3254
         id: 2,
         parent_id: null,
         title: "Parent",
         created_at: "2019-10-04 14:22:23",
         updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:22:23",
         children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3285
           all: [
             App\Item {#3287
               id: 3,
               parent_id: 2,
               title: "Child 1",
               created_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
               updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
             },
             App\Item {#3289
               id: 4,
               parent_id: 2,
               title: "Child 2",
               created_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
               updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
             },
           ],
         },
       },
       App\Item {#3259
         id: 3,
         parent_id: 2,
         title: "Child 1",
         created_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
         updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:29:59",
         children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3282
           all: [],
         },
       },
       App\Item {#3280
         id: 4,
         parent_id: 2,
         title: "Child 2",
         created_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
         updated_at: "2019-10-04 14:30:16",
         children: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3275
           all: [],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

As you can see, the items are returned as `children`, but also as single (duplicate) items in the list.

### My code

**Item**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable
        = [
            'title',
        ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'parent_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

How I get the related `items`:

```
$user->items()->with('children')->get();
```

Comment: So an Item has itself as a parent and has many of its siblings as children! I failed to see the business logic here

Comment: Hi Caddy DZ. That's correct: An item can have a parent and other `Item` instances as child. Example: A category can have a parent-category and many child-categories, which can have child-categories as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query items that are parents, couple of ways here

```php
$user->items()->whereDoesntHave('parent')->with('children')->get();
```

Or

```php
$user->items()->with('children')->where('parent_id', null)->get();
```

Now you wouldn't get the duplicated results

Answer (score 1):

You can get the items without parent_id first using whereNull()

Then load the children of those using with()

```
$user->items() whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();
```